# eslint no-unused-vars when using js classes

Tags: javascript, eslint

When I declare a class with ctor, and then use this class only as a function's input parameter, I get no-unused-vars from eslint.

Code:

```
/**
 * A class
 */
class SampleClass{
    /**
     * Ctor
     * @param {string} par - a parameter
     */
    constructor(par) {
        this.par = par;
    }
}

/**
 * Func
 * @param {SampleClass} param - a sample class
 * @returns {SampleClass} - the same class
 */
function fName(param) {
    return param;
}
```

So as you can see, I use SampleClass both as input parameter and as return type of the function, but eslint shows error: 'A class "SampleClass" is defined but never used. eslint no-unused-vars'

How can i fix this? Of course, I need to leave this type of check workong.

Comment: Aren't you confusing a class with a type? And a parameter with a parameter type?

Comment: _"I use SampleClass both as input parameter and as return type of the function"_ - there is no such type-checking in javascript.

Comment: Try adding export before your `class` and `function`. The eslint error is because of your class and function not being used anywhere else.

Comment: Can JSdoc take actual JavaSript objects like that. It is a comment so I am not sure it is actually "used". Just ignore the warning with eslint-ignore line maybe.

Comment: Nisanth, you're suggesting to put a frame to hide a hole in the wall 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to use a cleverer eslint parser - @babel/eslintparser. It does not raise this error when I use classes.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't fully understand what you wanted to do with that function and class, but within my understanding, I think this would work

```
 class SampleClass {
        constructor(par){
            this.par = par;
        }

    getInstance() {
        return this.par
    }
}


function fName(params) {
    return params
}

const newClass = new SampleClass("param");

fName(newClass.getInstance())
```